# SQL query not going through due to error in SQL syntax? phpmyadmin

Tags: php, sql

I am typing in this query:

i13 display name, price and sum quantity for all fruit, even ones with quantity null

```
select inventory.fruitID
concat( "$", quantity * price ) as "value"
from fruit right join inventory
on fruit.fruitID = inventory.fruitID;
```

I am getting this message:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '( "$", quantity * price ) as "value" from fruit right join
>   inventory on fruit.fr' at line 3

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are the quotes around the query single '' ie not double ""

Comment: yes they're the double marks "

Comment: try single ....

Comment: There's a comma missing before the `concat()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you want *all* fruit, then use a `left join` with `fruit` as the first table.  I think the query you are trying for is:

```
select f.fruitID, f.price, sum(i.quantity) as total_quantity
from fruit f left join
     inventory i
     on f.fruitID = i.fruitID
group by f.fruitID, f.price;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- This assumes that `price` is in the `fruit` table.
- If you want all `fruit`, then `fruit` should be the first table in the `left join`.
- You see to want to sum the inventory, so that requires an aggregation function and `group by`.